# 2018 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, status-completed, election

Emacs's [second moderator election](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the new moderator is:

[image: DoMiNeLa10]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking Jordan Biondo who will be stepping down as moderator.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4792585491054592/0).

Answer (score 5):

Congratulations for winning the elections @DoMiNeLa10 .

I wish that you will enjoy the role and make the most of the time spent here to help make Emacs SE the welcoming place that it is.

Comment: Thank you for offering your candidacy and your grace in congratulating the winner.  Please consider nominating yourself again the next time we have an election.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness, @Dan . For now I happily continue communicating with you and participating as I always do.