# 2020 Potential Moderator Election: Community Interest Check

Tags: discussion, election

It's time for us to consider holding an election for
moderators for Emacs.SE.

The last election we held
was
[back in 2018](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/527/2018-community-moderator-election-results),
and since then two of our moderators have resigned (see their
explanations
[here](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/555/i-am-resigning-as-a-moderator) and
[here](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/556/im-resigning-from-moderating-on-stack-exchange)).
That leaves just one moderator (yours truly) to mind the shop,
along with our active members.

So: we should hold a new election to get ourselves back up to the
standard three moderators.  To avoid finding ourselves in a
situation where an election would fail due to an insufficient
number of candidates, though, I'm posting this to try to assess
the community members' willingness to step up and nominate
themselves, when the actual election's nomination period starts.

**Please leave an answer if you'd be willing to run for a moderator
position, should we decide to run an election.**

NOTE: This is not an official election nomination thread, just a
"pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be
willing to step up.

Answer (score 2):

I am happy to volunteer to anything emacs, after all, I use it daily.